# Send attachment to gmail id from shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, email

I have a shell script that generates reports. Using crontab I run the scrip everyday at 1000 hrs.

I want to mail that report to my gmail id as an attachment.

I have tried using mutt but it doesn't work for me.

After installing sendEmail, when I am attempting to send the mail I am getting the following information

```
Sep 14 15:15:37 debal sendEmail[3671]: DEBUG => Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
Sep 14 15:15:38 debal sendEmail[3671]: DEBUG => My IP address is: 192.168.2.103
Sep 14 15:15:38 debal sendEmail[3671]: SUCCESS => Received:     220 mx.google.com ESMTP uw6sm17314211pbc.8 - gsmtp
Sep 14 15:15:38 debal sendEmail[3671]: INFO => Sending:     EHLO debal
Sep 14 15:15:38 debal sendEmail[3671]: SUCCESS => Received:     250-mx.google.com at your service, [180.151.208.181], 250-SIZE 35882577, 250-8BITMIME, 250-STARTTLS, 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES, 250 CHUNKING
Sep 14 15:15:38 debal sendEmail[3671]: INFO => Sending:     STARTTLS
Sep 14 15:15:38 debal sendEmail[3671]: SUCCESS => Received:     220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
*******************************************************************
 Using the default of SSL_verify_mode of SSL_VERIFY_NONE for client
 is deprecated! Please set SSL_verify_mode to SSL_VERIFY_PEER
 together with SSL_ca_file|SSL_ca_path for verification.
 If you really don't want to verify the certificate and keep the
 connection open to Man-In-The-Middle attacks please set
 SSL_verify_mode explicitly to SSL_VERIFY_NONE in your application.
*******************************************************************
  at /usr/local/bin/sendEmail line 1906.
invalid SSL_version specified at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 414.
```

I did a yum install on perl-Net-SSLeay perl-Net-SMTP-SSL and this is the result.

```
[root@debal ~]# yum install perl-Net-SSLeay perl-Net-SMTP-SSL
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Package perl-Net-SSLeay-1.54-1.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package perl-Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01-13.fc19.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

The problem still persists and I am using Fedora 19.

Comment: If you already have your MTA configured to send mail correctly, you can tell sendEmail to use it.   use sendEmail's `-S` option instead of `-s "${RELAY_SERVER}"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/)

**About SendEmail**

> SendEmail is a lightweight, command line SMTP email client. If you
>   have the need to send email from a command line, this free program is
>   perfect: simple to use and feature rich. It was designed to be used in
>   bash scripts, batch files, Perl programs and web sites, but is quite
>   adaptable and will likely meet your requirements. SendEmail is written
>   in Perl and is unique in that it requires NO MODULES. It has an
>   intuitive and flexible set of command-line options, making it very
>   easy to learn and use. SendEmail is licensed under the GNU GPL, either
>   version 2 of the License or (at your option) any later version.
>   [Supported Platforms: Linux, BSD, OS X, Windows 98, Windows NT,
>   Windows 2000, & Windows XP]

Following Script I used to install sendEmail  and send mail to gmail id in CentOS/RHEL

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Define sender's detail  email ID
From_Mail="your_email@gmail.com"

# Sender's Username and password account for sending mail
Sndr_Uname="${From_Mail}"
Sndr_Passwd="your_password"

# Define recepient's email ID
To_Mail="to_send@gmail.com"

# Define CC to (Note: for multiple CC use ,(comma) as seperator )
# CC_TO="loginrahul90@gmail.com"

# Define mail server for sending mail [ IP:PORT or HOSTNAME:PORT ]
RELAY_SERVER="smtp.gmail.com:587"

# Subject
Subject="Test Mail using SendEmail"

# sendEmail download link
download_sendEmail="http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/sendEmail-v1.56.tar.gz"


# Mail Body

MSG() {

cat <<_EOF
Dear Sir,

    Please find the attachment of PDF File

_EOF

}


# store loggin information in below log file
Log_File="/var/log/sendmail.log"

# check sendmail dir exists or not if not check create it
Log_dir="$(dirname ${Log_File})"


if [ ! -d "${Log_dir}" ]; then

    mkdir "${Log_dir}"

fi



check_sendmail() {

    if [ ! -x "/usr/bin/sendEmail" ]; then
        echo "sendEmail not installed"
        echo "Installing sendEmail..."
        sleep 1s
        wget -cnd "${download_sendEmail}" -O /tmp/sendemail.tar.gz >/dev/null 2>&1
        tar -xzf /tmp/sendemail.tar.gz  --wildcards  *sendEmail
        install --mode=744 sendEmail*/sendEmail /usr/bin/
        yum install perl-Net-SSLeay perl-Net-SMTP-SSL -y
    fi
}



check_sendmail

/usr/bin/sendEmail -v -f ${From_Mail} \
                     -t ${To_Mail} -u "${Subject}" \
                     -m `MSG` \
                     -xu "${Sndr_Uname}" \
                     -xp "${Sndr_Passwd}" \
                     -o tls=auto \
                     -s "${RELAY_SERVER}" \
                     -cc "${CC_TO}" \
                     -l "${Log_File}"
```

You can use `-a` option for file attachment to `sendEmail` command

Comment: edited my question to include the error message i am getting.

Comment: which distro you are using ? ubuntu or redhat ?

Comment: if you are using RHEL/CentOS then make sure `perl-Net-SSLeay perl-Net-SMTP-SSL` packages should be install , OR if you are using Ubuntu then check package `libnet-smtp-tls-perl`

Comment: Some more update